# How to locate the first element in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a question, 
I have this xpath that return 9 results

```
//nz-select[(@formcontrolname='deviceType')]
```

I want to locate the first element, so I tried in the xpath the following

```
//nz-select[(@formcontrolname='deviceType')][1]
//nz-select[1][(@formcontrolname='deviceType')]
```

however in the F12 console it always 9 results. how can I locate the [1] results, without putting all in list and other issues.
Just want hard coded the results of the first one
regards

Answer (score 3):

To get the first item Try this **xpath**.

```
(//nz-select[@formcontrolname='deviceType'])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

(.//nz-select[(@formcontrolname='deviceType')])[1]